# knockoutjs - bind text and event is not working?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockoutjs to bind data, I have a problem to bind text and event at the same time, here is code:

```
<input type="text"  id="txtTextbox" data-bind="text: code, textInput : strCode, event: {keypress: addCode}"/>
```

It's not working, so there is any something wrong and how to fix it? (My view model is normally).

Comment: `input` type has default `value` binding not `text` & clarify what `textInput` intend to do there .

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with it as written.  Firstly you want to use either "value" rather than "text" binding.  Usually you will only use one or other of "value" and "textInput", depending on whether you require constant updates (then use "textInput") or updates only on blur (then use "value").

If this doesn't resolve your problem please post specifics of what is not working.